# FileTable: изменить место хранения файлов

Tags: sql, sql-server, filestream

Как в SqlServer 2016 создать каталог для FileTable на другом сервере.

Команда

```
 CREATE TABLE FILES AS FILETABLE
 WITH
 (
     FILETABLE_DIRECTORY = '\\fileserver-1\FILES',
     FILETABLE_COLLATE_FILENAME = database_default
 )
```

даёт ошибку:

> An invalid directory name '\\fileserver-1\FILES' was specified. Use a
>   valid Windows directory name.

Comment: Как вариант, создайте сетевой диск.

Comment: @nick_n_a, в `FILETABLE_DIRECTORY` указал сетевой диск `Z:\Test`. Таже ошибка `An invalid directory name 'Z:\Test' was specified. Use a valid Windows directory name.`

Comment: символическую ссылку попробуйте ему скормить. Я так понимаю, что указываемый каталог `_DIRECTORY` располагается относительно директории, где хранятся сами БД? подмените каталог на симлинк `mklink /D files "\\fileserver-1\FILES"`, `cmd` только от админа запустите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Параметр *FILETABLE_DIRECTORY* вовсе не задаёт путь, по которому будут храниться данные файловой таблицы. Этот параметр служит вот для чего.

В SqlServer есть возможность настроить доступ к файловым таблицам так, что они будут видны через UNC-share, путь которой при этом имеет вид:

```
\\Host_Name\Instance_FilestreamShare\Database_FilestreamDirectory\Filetable_Directory
```

Вторая часть пути (по умолчанию - *MSSQLSERVER*) задаётся в конфигураторе инстанса, третья часть пути - в свойствах БД, четвертая же часть как раз и определяется параметром *FILETABLE_DIRECTORY* и по умолчанию совпадает с именем таблицы.

Т.е. если filestream директория БД задана как *DbNameFilestream*, и мы создавали таблицу следующей командой

```sql
CREATE TABLE FILES AS FILETABLE;
```

то UNC-путь до неё будет выглядеть как-то так

```
\\HostName\MSSQLSERVER\DbNameFilestream\FILES
```

Если же по какой-либо причине нужно изменить имя директории, соответствующее файловой таблице, то применяется параметр *FILETABLE_DIRECTORY*

```sql
CREATE TABLE FILES AS FILETABLE
WITH
(
    FILETABLE_DIRECTORY = 'SOMEFILES'
);
```

в этом случае UNC-путь до файловой таблицы будет

```
\\HostName\MSSQLSERVER\DbNameFilestream\SOMEFILES
```

---

Что касается места хранения filestream данных, то оно определяется соответствующей файловой группой и директориями, включёнными в неё (и их может быть несколько).

Если нужно, чтобы файлы, располагающиеся в файловой таблице, лежали в определённой директории, то нужно создать выделенную файловую группу для filestream данных:

```sql
ALTER DATABASE [DbName]
    ADD FILEGROUP [SomeFilegroup] CONTAINS FILESTREAM;
```

Добавить в неё нужную директорию:

```sql
ALTER DATABASE [DbName]
    ADD FILE (
        NAME = N'Some',
        FILENAME = N'N:\Some'
    ) TO FILEGROUP [SomeFilegroup];
```

И при создании таблицы указать соответствующую файловую группу для filestream данных таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE FILES AS FILETABLE
    FILESTREAM_ON [SomeFilegroup];
```

Директория, включённая в файловую группу, должна располагаться на локальном диске и, к сожалению, не может быть сетевой. Впрочем, [по-видимому](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd695918.aspx), если есть возможность посредством *iSCSI* подключить сетевое хранилище как локальный диск, то можно этим воспользоваться.